# How to access different test-fragment present in external test plan

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to create a common test plan and define multiple test fragment in this file. I want to use some of the specific test fragment in the specific test plan. Here is outline of two different test plan.

```
common-test-plan.jmx
 common-test-plan
  |--TestFragment1
  |   |-Sampler11
  | 
  |--TestFragment2
      |-Sampler21

Specific-test-plan.jmx
 Some-Test-plan
  |--ThreadGroup1
     |-IncludeController
     |-Module controller(accessing the Include controller)
     |-Sampler1
     |-Sampler2
```

I used include controller to include the external test plan component. When I use the Module controller it just shows the include controller in the list. It doesn't show all test fragment present in the external test plan.

Is there any way I can specifically use few of the test fragment present in the external test?

Answer (score 1):

IncludeController references aren't loaded until you run
the test plan which means that the ModuleController can't reference its
internals

The best you have without a code change is one TestFragment per
IncludeController and then to use a TestFragment in your main Test Plan to
Include them all.  ModuleControllers can then reference each included file
to execute its contents.

Answer based on Anthony Johnson on mailing list

Comment: Thanks for sharing it here. I already got response from Anthony.

Comment: I made it community wiki so that you can accept it without us getting the points.